# Why is OLS estimator of AR(1) coefficient biased?

Tags: time-series, least-squares, bias, autoregressive, estimators

I am trying to understand why OLS gives a biased estimator of an AR(1) process. Consider 
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{t} &= \alpha + \beta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}, \\
\epsilon_{t} &\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1).
\end{aligned}
$$
In this model, strict exogeneity is violated, i.e. $y_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ are correlated but $y_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_t$ are uncorrelated. But if this is true, then why does the following simple derivation not hold?
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{plim} \ \hat{\beta} &= \frac{\text{Cov}(y_{t},y_{t-1})}{\text{Var}(y_{t-1})} \\
&=\frac{\text{Cov}(\alpha + \beta y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}, y_{t-1})}{\text{Var}(y_{t-1})} \\
&= \beta+ \frac{\text{Cov}(\epsilon_{t}, y_{t-1})}{\text{Var}(y_{t-1})} \\
&=\beta. 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: There have been a few related questions at Cross Validated. You could benefit from looking them up.

Comment: I saw them, but they did not really help me. I found a proof and simulations that show this result. What I am interested in is what is wrong with my reasoning above.

Comment: When you are using $\text{plim}$, aren't you addressing consistency rather than (un)biasedness? For (un)biasedness you should be using expectations.

Comment: You are completely right, that could solve the puzzle. So if the equation above does not hold without a plim, then it would not contradict the biasedness of OLS in small samples and show the consistency of OLS at the same time. Though I am a bit unsure: Does this covariance over variance formula really only hold for the plim and not also in expectation? Thanks a lot already!

Comment: OLS estimator itself does not involve any $\text{plim}$s, you should just look at expectations in finite samples.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As essentially discussed in the comments, unbiasedness is a finite sample property, and if it held it would be expressed as

$$E (\hat \beta ) = \beta$$

(where the expected value is the first moment of the finite-sample distribution)

while consistency is an asymptotic property expressed as

$$\text{plim} \hat \beta = \beta$$

The OP shows that even though OLS in this context is biased, it is still consistent.

$$E (\hat \beta ) \neq \beta\;\;\; \text{but}\;\;\; \text{plim} \hat \beta = \beta$$

No contradiction here.

Answer (score 9):

@Alecos nicely explains why a correct plim and unbiasedbess are not the same. As for the underlying reason why the estimator is not unbiased, recall that unbiasedness of an estimator requires that *all* error terms are mean independent of *all* regressor values, $E(\epsilon|X)=0$.

In the present case, the regressor matrix consists of the values $y_1,\ldots,y_{T-1}$, so that - see mpiktas' comment - the condition translates into $E(\epsilon_s|y_1,\ldots,y_{T-1})=0$ for all $s=2,\ldots,T$.

Here, we have

\begin{equation*}
y_{t}=\beta y_{t-1}+\epsilon _{t},
\end{equation*}
Even under the assumption $E(\epsilon_{t}y_{t-1})=0$ we have that
\begin{equation*}
E(\epsilon_ty_{t})=E(\epsilon_t(\beta y_{t-1}+\epsilon _{t}))=E(\epsilon _{t}^{2})\neq 0.
\end{equation*}
But, $y_t$ is also a regressor for future values in ain AR model, as $y_{t+1}=\beta y_{t}+\epsilon_{t+1}$.

Comment: I would add the clarification that $E(\varepsilon | X)$ in this case translates to $E(\varepsilon_s|y_{1},...,y_T)$ for each $s$. Then the further discussion becomes a bit clearer.

Comment: good point, I made an edit

Comment: The last equation is wrong, $E(\epsilon_t y_t) = E(\epsilon_t (\beta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-1})) = 0$

Comment: No, see the definition of the AR(1) process in the display above which I plugged in there. $y_t$ is the combination of its lagged value $y_{t-1}$ plus the *current* innovaton $\epsilon_t$.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on two good answers. Write down the OLS estimator:

$$\hat\beta =\beta + \frac{\sum_{t=2}^Ty_{t-1}\varepsilon_t}{\sum_{t=2}^Ty_{t-1}^2}$$

For unbiasedness we need

$$E\left[\frac{\sum_{t=2}^Ty_{t-1}\varepsilon_t}{\sum_{t=2}^Ty_{t-1}^2}\right]=0.$$

But for that we need that $E(\varepsilon_t|y_{1},...,y_{T-1})=0,$ for each $t$. For AR(1) model this clearly fails, since $\varepsilon_t$ is related to the future values $y_{t},y_{t+1},...,y_{T}$.

Comment: Just to check whether I got it right: The problem is not the numerator, for each t $y_{t-1}$ and $\epsilon_{t}$ are uncorrelated. The problem is the denominator that features higher t's such that there is correlation between numerator and denominator so that I cannot take the expectation within the sum of the numerator (under strict exogeneity I could do so?!). Is that the correct mathematical intuition?

Comment: Yes that is correct intuition. Note that strict exogeneity is not possible in this case, but for unbiasedness strict exogeneity becomes a requirement.

Comment: Do you know what the finite sample distribution is of OLS estimates for AR(1) (assuming Gaussian driving noise)? Thank you

Comment: Your equation for the OLS estimator is wrong, you didn't center the $y$s correctly.

Comment: @Florestan the numerator is problematic too, because $\epsilon_t$ is strongly correlated with the means of the $y$s, $\sum^T_{t=2} y_{t-1} / (T -1)$.